# css positioning problem show different result in different browser

Tags: css

i have a blog and i have placed a form in right but it shows different result in different browser.

The  Link named "Subcribe in a reader" should be in center but it shows in left in Safari and Opera but IN FF and Ie7 Shows Perfectly in center.
And The border is 5-6 pixel going up in Opera and Safari but in FF & IE 7 it shows Perfectly fine. And In Ie6 it shows border line 10-12 pixel downside ... strange

i m using   this code to adjust for postioning..
please help....

**my blog : ww.techieinspire.blogspot.com**

check image here
http://techie2inspire.googlepages.com/csspositioningproblem.JPG

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of cross-browser support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is seriously jacked up. Use Firebug on Firefox to look at it. Here's a couple things I noticed:

1. You have your elements for your subscribe link inside the form above it. This is not apart of your newsletter form, so shouldn't be contained inside that form.
2. Your using a lot of `<span>`s with block elements inside them. `<span>`s are generally for inline content and sticking block elements (like `<p>`) inside could give weird results.
3. Check your stylesheets where your setting the left padding for ".newsletter p" this is affecting your subscription link.
4. Try to avoid specifying styles inline (using the style attribute).
5. Stop using postion:relative everywhere. Instead using padding and margins for layout your sidebar.

Generally to center something, you can do this:

```
.centered_thing {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Edit: The marquee thing is terrible. Read about what happened to the [HTML marquee tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_tag). There's many good reasons to avoid it or Javascript knockoffs.

Comment: thanks you where right .newletter p padding was affecting it..however i used center tag and removed all span tag..thanks for help

Comment: i forgot to ask you commented on marquee.so you mean that i should remove marquee tag.I have added bcoz it looks good and professional too

Comment: I'm not so sure many people would agree that it looks professional, but to each his own ;)